# Getting Aeson to deal with a mixed-type list

Tags: haskell, aeson

This works:

```
λ decode "[\"one\", \"two\"]" :: Maybe [Text]
Just ["one","two"]
```

This works:

```
λ decode "[1, 2]" :: Maybe [Int]
Just [1,2]
```

This is perfectly-valid JSON but I can't make it work:

```
λ decode "[\"one\", 2]" :: Maybe [Text]
Nothing
```

Or even:

```
λ decode "[2]" :: Maybe [Text]
Nothing
```

I would like to convince the last to give me:

```
Just ["one","2"]
Just ["2"]
```

But no way I can see to twist Aeson's arm into seeing something it wants to see as a number as a string instead.

Update:

```
λ decode "[1, \"2\"]" :: Maybe Array
Just (fromList [Number 1.0,String "2"])
```

I guess that's a little better. I still wish I could get Aeson to coerce everything to strings but I guess I can work with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard `FromJSON` instance for `Text` will not do the kind of coercion you're looking for. Fortunately, `aeson` is flexible enough to let you define your own types with their own rules. Here's an example, [complete on FP Haskell Center](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/chad/snippets/random-code-snippets/getting-aeson-to-deal-with-a-mixed-type-list). The main part of it is:

```
newtype LaxText = LaxText Text
    deriving Show

instance FromJSON LaxText where
    parseJSON (String t) = return $ LaxText t
    parseJSON (Number n) = return $ LaxText $ toStrict $ toLazyText $ scientificBuilder n
    parseJSON _ = fail "Invalid LaxText"
```